# Experiencing error generateLockfiles for gradle

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle, gradlew

I'm new to app development and I keep getting this error even though the project is completely new.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqDcO.png)

Here is my app level gradle file

```
plugins
{
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.1' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is my android level gradle file

```
plugins
{
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.1' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I've tried troubleshooting the version number of the google services, Java, and Gradle but nothing seems to be working. If anyone has some advice please send it my way!